# LUISGEN Failed to generate LUIS Model when LUIS have Complex entities with subentities

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Currently I'm using LUISGen to help my bot to get Intent and Entities easily in C#.

My LUIS APP have main entity with subentities.
[image]

Here, I am using LUISGen to generating C# class for a LUIS app and getting the below error

```
   Exception Info: System.ArgumentException: Can not convert Object to String.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.op_Explicit(JToken value)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at LUISGen.Utils.EntityApply(JObject entity, Action`1 action) in D:\a\1\s\packages\LUISGen\src\Utils.cs:line 94
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at LUISGen.CSharp.Entities(Object app, Writer w) in D:\a\1\s\packages\LUISGen\src\CSharp.cs:line 161
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at LUISGen.CSharp.Generate(String description, Object app, String className, String space, String outPath) in D:\a\1\s\packages\LUISGen\src\CSharp.cs:line
```

Comment: Can you please share the Luisgen commands that you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in luis:convert and has been fixed since our last release. If you are using the pre-release version of bf and  I tried doing luis:generate:cs on the .json file and failed with the same error. you can then doing luis:convert and then luis:generate:cs and it worked.

If you  want to run the pre-release  version of the bf tool, do the below.

1. Point npm at the MyGet feed: npm config set registry https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/botframework-cli/npm/
2. Install the CLI tool: npm install -g @microsoft/botframework-cli

You should install and try using bf luis:generate:cs https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/blob/master/packages/luis/README.md#bf-luisgeneratecs for pre-release.

Comment: Is this issue fixed? I still get the error.

Comment: Why isn't this issue being documented in official docs?